# How to send data in batches from django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make an android application for which I am using Django as backend.

I have a listing page which shows me all product available on my application. Suppose I have 2000 products available on my application so want to send these data into batches of 10 or 20.

So I am a little bit confused about how can I send data into batches.
Provide some sample code if possible.
Thanks in advance

```
@csrf_exempt
def ShowProducts(request):
    pro_object = Product.objects.all()
    data = pro_object

    return JsonResponse({'data':data})
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django `Paginator` to achieve that,  for more details check the documentation here [Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/)

In your case, you can do something like:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.http import JsonResponse

def show_products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(products, 10)  # to show 10 products

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return JsonResponse({'data': products.object_list})
```

Comment: i am getting this error `<Page 1 of 3> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Use `products.object_list` instead of `products`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use pagination in front end call as follows:-

views.py

```
class subProjectsList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        pageNo = int(request.GET['pageNo'])
        perPage = int(request.GET['perPage'])
        start_limit = (pageNo-1) * perPage
        end_limit = pageNo * perPage

        productsCount = Product.objects.all().count()
        products = Product.objects.all()[start_limit:end_limit]

        data = {'success':True,'msg':'YourMsg','rows':result,'count':allSubProjectsCount}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),content_type="application/json")
```

At front End you can code something like this(Angular JS):-

```
var pageNo = 1;
var perPage = jo teri marzi;
$scope.result = [];

angular.forEach(response, function (value) {
  $scope.result.push(value);
  });
  $scope.totalCount = response.count;
  if($scope.totalCount > 0){
       if(Math.ceil($scope.totalCount/perPage) !== pageNo){
              pageNo = pageNo + 1;
              callthemethodAgain();
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the following

1. Django Rest 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/
2. Otherwise you can use django serializers + django pagination 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/